# Compare web content with the CSV File

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, data-driven, csv-file

I want to compare my data in CSV with the web content. The data in CSV file comprises of multiple rows and column. How can I verify that the data inputted on the web is correct comparing it with the CSV using Jmeter?

There is a search bar on the website I write any character I get the location of particular dealers along with the details and I have data in CSV and now I want to compare the data entered on the web is correct or not

EDIT: the data on the web is called through AJAX.

Comment: Your tool choice is not suitable for your stated objective, it appears to be a data validation exercise.  JMeter is most suitable for performance/load/stress testing.  If your actual objective is functional testing the data loading, transfer and presentation, then look toward appropriate functional test tools.  SOAPUI with some Groovy for the AJAX API, Cucumber and Selenium WebDriver if you want the test the data through a WebApp.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should go something like:

1. Create a [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) which will perform the search on the website
2. Extract "interesting" parts of the response using one of [JMeter's Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
3. Compare expected value (i.e. variable from CSV) with the actual value (i.e. variable from the PostProcessor) using [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you elaborate more?

Answer (score -1):

I may not follow you exactly, but it's usual to have some kind of input file with sample test data and expected outcomes. This may be CSV, Excel, or wiki for example. For an old school example of driving tests this way, look into [Fitnesse](http://docs.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide). It looks like there's a similar and newer project, [Gauge](https://gauge.org/), that might be worth a look as well--I have no experience with this one. Hope it helps!